# How can you attach a content item as an element field of another content item via its authoring template?

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm

Let's say I defined a IBM WCM authoring template called **"AT-Image"**; it creates content item **"CT-Image"** that contains elements such as an *Image* of type "Image", *Description* of type "Short Text", *Keywords* of type "Text", and other fields that serve as meta for that image resource.

Now, I need to create a content item called **"CT-Article"** based off from its **"AT-Article"** authoring template.  Let's say that "Article" item has 3 elements: *Title*, *Summary*, and *Image*.  *Title* and *Summary* are of type "Short Text".  But *Image* needs to be of type "CT-Image" and not *Image* or *Image component*.

Is this possible Out-of-the-Box or is this something I need to implement myself via WCM API?

Comment: take a look on rendering plugins, something like this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/notes/entry/wcm_rendering_pluging24?lang=en. If you will find native way to render embedded cotnent - let me know

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view you should use a menu component in the following way:

Let's assume you have got your CT-Image and CT-Article in a common sitearea called "MyArticle" like this:

```
 MyArticle
     CT-Article
     CT-Image
```

Furthermore you need a WCM Menu component which uses two selection criteria:

1. current sitearea as location
2. CT-Image as authoring template

So then rendering CT-Article with a presentation template PT-Article you can reference the menu component. Therefore, you reference the menu component in the presentation template markup. The menu component then will pick up the CT-Image and render it as it is located in the same sitearea as your CT-Article.

That's rather a content design approach then a technical approach. It's all there out-of-the-box and saves custom development effort.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, basically you want to create pre-defined images and then pick one of them to display when you create an article. Correct?

Well, the easiest way would be to utilize what WCM already gives you: create an **Image Component**. You will be able to upload the image and also provide a description, but you won't be able to set keywords or metadata. The workaround for this would be to set the keywords/metadata as part of the article. If that is okay, this would probably be the best way to do it.

By doing that, all you would have to do is select the relevant Image Component from your Image Element in AT-Article.

If you really need the images to be their own content items (rather than components) so that they have their own keywords and other information, then the next "easiest" way is probably to use an HTML Element inside AT-Article. In this  HTML Element you will have to use the "Insert Tag" option, and then choose an Element Tag and use "Selected" rather than "autofill" or "current" to navigate to the content item that you want (the one with the image).

The code will look like this:

```
[Element name="[path]" type="content" context="selected" key="[element]"]
```

Where [path] is the path to the content item and [element] is the element that you actually want to pull from that content item (such as image, description, keywords, etc.)

context="selected" is the key there. Then you just need to set up your Presentation Template to be able to use this information that you are pulling in from the HTML Element.

Answer (score 0):

WCM 8.5 has the InContext tag.
The InContext tag renders a tag body within a specified context. The new context can be specified as a predefined context by using a UUID, or by path.

For eg. in this case you can use below where key="Image" in InContext tag is the Link element to the CT-Image content item :

```
[InContext uuid="[Element context='current' type='content' key='Image' format='id']"]
[Element context="current" type="auto" key="Image"]
[Element context="current" type="auto" key="Description"]
[/InContext]
```